# Wordpress 404 - Error - This page does not exist

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, elementor

I am trying to set up my first wordpress site, but it is showing "This page does not exist", the header and footer are working. I have already tried to:

- Update / reset Permalinks
- Create / reset .htaccess files
- Disable plugins and themes

Do you know what else can I check?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have just realized that my home page setup was set to private... I have changed to public and now its fine!